# 1 SSL Certificate to serve separate servers

Tags: ssl, https, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have little knowledge of SSL and have the following scenario:

Server 1 - Domain and Hosting for www.mywebsite.com - Has SSL Cert.
Server 2 - Hosting for forum.mywebsite.com - No SSL Cert.

I require an SSL cert for server 2, bought a standard one and was told by the hosting provider it cannot be installed or used.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Where would this be best placed then @KenWhite?

Comment: I think it probably belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I require an SSL cert for server 2, bought a standard one and was told by the hosting provider it cannot be installed or used.

Technically speaking, you can obtain an SSL certificate from any trusted public Certification Authority, and you should be able to install it in any web server. Therefore, there are no connections between where you obtain the certificate and where you install it.

However, your hosting provider may impose certain limitations. For example, they may not allow you to install arbitrary SSL certificates as they offer it as an integrated product.

Without further details, it's difficult to provide a more detailed answer. Suffice to say that there are no specific limitations, the reason why your provider is telling you it cannot be installed or used is their own decision/policy/limitation.